# Android DatePicker crashes when setting minDate or maxDate on kitkat

Tags: android

Hello I have a datepicker dialog that pops up when the user taps on an EditText.  It works on another device I tried it on which run Android 6.0 however when I tried the same app on a table that run kitkat it crashed.

I can confirm it is the setMinDate or setMaxDate code because I took that out and the page didn't crash after I did.

This is the log:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.xxxxxx.pointofsale, PID: 13402
>                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                   at android.widget.CalendarView.onScroll(CalendarView.java:1216)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.CalendarView.access$900(CalendarView.java:76)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.CalendarView$2.onScroll(CalendarView.java:1077)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1463)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1745)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2149)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1877)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1653)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
>                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2323)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2029)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
>                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
>                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Nativ

This is my code:

```
  final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {

            mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

            mSelectedDate = sdf.format(mCalendar.getTime());
            etDate.setText(Utils.formatDate(mSelectedDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", "EEEE, d MMMM yyyy"));
            getTravelSchedules();
        }

    };

    private final View.OnClickListener mDateViewOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etDate.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select a destination first!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            Date today = new Date();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(today);
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, +7);
            final long maxDate = c.getTime().getTime();

            c.setTime(today);
            final long minDate = c.getTime().getTime();

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, R.style.DialogTheme, mDateSetListener, mCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this function also like**

```
void showDatePickerDialog(final EditText et) {

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
           et.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(myCalendar.getTime()));     
        }
    };

    // Calendar Minimum Range
    Calendar calendarMinDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarMinDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);

   // Calendar Maximum Range
    Calendar calendarMaxDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarMaxDate.add(Calendar.DATE, +7);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            R.style.MyDatePickerDialogTheme, date, calYear, calMonth, calDay);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendarMinDate.getTimeInMillis());
  datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendarMaxDate.getTimeInMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Alright so basically instead of setting the min and max date on the datepickerdialog itself I add it to the calendar instead, thanks will try it.

Comment: basically whats the crash shows.. can you show exactly

Comment: because this works for me perfectly irrespective of android version

Comment: It shows exactly what I posted in my question.  App has stocked working and that is what is in the logs.  I did some research and it seems to be a known android bug, can set min date, can set max date but can't set both on anything less than API 19 or it will crash.

Comment: thats not possible, i make apps that can even run on 17 and it works fine there

Comment: calenderview.scroll listener doesn't make any sense with dialogpicker because we are using native and not overriding any scroll listener within this. If possible please reconfirm your exception, if the dialogpicker is the real problem or something else